# How can i check if 3 letters entered are in a consecutive order of a qwer keyboard?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say the user enters 'hkuzasd7854hjd;a' on a keyboard 'asd' are letters next to each other. Is there a simple way I could make a loop that goes through the 3 rows of the keys on a keyboard and checks if the value entered by the user contains 3 consecutive letters?Is it possible to make the code return an integer value instead of a true or false?. Thank you.

Comment: What attempts have been made so far? A loop is simple. Defining your own list of keys is too

Comment: What should be the meaning of the returned integer value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there are so few consecutive 3-letter sequences, that you can list them:

```
BAD3 = { 
    "qwe", "wer", "ert", "rty", "tyu", "yui", "uio", "iop",
    "asd", "sdf", "dfg", "fgh", "ghj", "hjk", "jkl",
    "zxc", "xcv", "cvb", "vbn" }

def qwertz(string):
    return any(bad in string for bad in BAD3)
```

Very primitive, I know. You could make a function for preparing the BAD set, if you prefer.

---

Updated function counting all occurrences (but e.g. "qwer" is counted twice, "qwe", "wer"):

```
def qwertz(string):
    return sum(1 for bad in BAD3 if bad in string )
```

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful and I will probably end up using this but how could you make a function for preparing the bad 3 set?

Comment: @Xotsu look at @StrongWill's code, the `string[y:y+3]` expression inside the loops contains the data you are looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to make the code return a value instead of a true or false? So for every time string is in BAD3. And what does bad do in this code, because I just assumed it represents 3 values.

Comment: @Xotsu: The `bad` is used in a so called generator expression.

Comment: @Xotsu: It should be very easy to modify the function to better suit your needs. You have to do it yourself as stackoverflow is a platform for interesting programming questions.

Comment: I'm probably just annoying you at this point but I've tried to make your code give an integer value but it just comes up with 1 `if any(abc in string for abc in BAD3) == True:
            y=y+1`

Comment: @Xotsu I'm sorry, but I do not understand what integer value you have on your mind. Given the input from your question 'hkuzasd7854hjd;a', what should be the integer output and why?

Comment: 1 because there is only 1 group of 3 consecutive letters 'asd' in your input, however I have successfully found a solution by joining your and Strong will codes together

Comment: `"rty", "tyu", "yui"` and more are not adjascent charater sequences on my keyboard. Not everyone uses an US keyboard. Seem it is **not** that simple.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code adds and found pattern to a list. List "found" contains 4 sublists each represents a row on your keyboard. So "qwe" would be in the second sublist of found with index of 1.

```
rows = ["1234567890-=",
        "qwertyuiop",
        "asdfghjkl;'",
        "\zxcvbnm,."]


string = "qwertyytruasddffdsgs4rewewerw";

found = [[],[],[],[]]


for row_idx,x in enumerate(rows):
    for y in range(0, len(string)-3):
        #Forward match
        if string[y:y+3] in x:
            found[row_idx].append(string[y:y+3])
        #Backwards match
        if (string[y:y+3])[::-1] in x:
            found[row_idx].append(string[y:y+3])

print found
```

As to other keyboard layout you would need a separate list of rows for every one of them that you want to support.

Hope this was a bit helpful.

Comment: There's no need for regex to do simple substring checks. Just use `if x[y:y+3] in string`. You've also got a bunch of unnecessary stuff in your code, like parentheses around the `if` condition and semicolons at the end of some of your lines. Python isn't C or Java, you don't need that noise! I'd also suggest using `enumerate` rather than incrementing `row_idx` manually.

Comment: sorry I am not a python programmer I am very used to c/c++ but thank you for pointing out I will fix it.